# Access folder on network drive with username password

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command, command-prompt

I currently have a script which runs a silent install of a program from the network drive. However, the problem is that in order to access these files I need to enter a username and password. Does anyone know how I can do that? This is what I have currently

```
start "" /wait "\\NetworkDrive\setup.exe" /adminfile "%~dp0outlook2013.msp"
```

Would I just need to add

```
{password} USER:admin
```

To the end?

Comment: Have you tried mounting the network drive using [`net use`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true) (which has a `/user` parameter) first?

Comment: Something like `net use N: \\NetworkDrive\folder /user admin password`

Comment: This is just for an installation batch file, so I don't want to map it. If I do net use, does it become mapped?

Comment: Yes. You can also disconnect the mapped drive immediately after the install using `net use N: /delete`.

Comment: I don't see why this question was downvoted. Good question, not really a duplicate of anything. Saved me some wasted time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is the usage of **net use** to temporary map a network drive for installation as suggested already by [admdrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454048/admdrew).

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use Z: \\Computer\ShareName\ password /user:admin /persistent:no
start "" /wait Z:\setup.exe /adminfile "%~dp0outlook2013.msp"
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use Z: /delete /yes
```

The parameter `/persistent:no` disables the storage of the network drive mapping in registry of Windows for automatic reconnect on next login by the user executing this batch file in case of batch file is terminated by the user before the line to delete the mapping of drive Z: could be executed.
That should not happen, but it is in general better to make a temporary mapping always with parameter `/persistent:no` to avoid recording this network drive connection in Windows registry at all.